# How to autofit Recycler View items to its height and width with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout, gridlayoutmanager

I'm writing a calendar app, so I have 28-31 items to show.

In the worst case, I will have 4 rows and 7 columns and in the best case, 5 rows and 7 columns.

I'm using `GridLayoutManager`, so:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 7)
```

I'm not using any code to change code in adapter, so:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DayViewHolder {
    var inflatedView = parent.inflate(R.layout.day_item_row)
    return DayViewHolder(inflatedView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DayViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val day = days[position]
}
```

My xml params for `RecyclerView`:

```
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/calendarRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
```

And for the item:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dayLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dayName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="5"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What is the best way to make items squares, that will be autofitted all `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have square elements inside of your RecyclerView, make the parent of the item layout (root view) a square ViewGroup. In this example i used FrameLayout but you can do the same with any. (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc.)

```
public class SquareFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public SquareFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public SquareFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // Set a square layout.
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

Comment: I made SquareConstraintLayout, and set it's width and height to match_parent, but now not all items in visible area of recyclerView, so i need scroll

Comment: Maybe this is something that you are locking for: https://gist.github.com/heinrichreimer/2fcb22f160eefee6f07b.